# How do I remove weight from a single bone in Blender

Tags: bones, weight-painting, vertex-groups

How do I remove weight from a single bone in Blender. I tried the eraser tool, but it doesn't get everything. I know I'm supposed to go to vertex groups and set the weight to zero, but I don't know how. I know how to select the bone in vertex groups, but I don't know how to set the weight to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an individual bone to not have any influence on mesh deformations, you can go into the bone's settings and turn off deformation. just uncheck that checkbox and it wont move any vertices around anymore.

[image: blender screencap showing deform checkbox]

I don't know if this is exactly what you want but maybe it'll help. good luck with your rigging!

Answer (score 1):

As Mcguest said, you can disable the *Deform* option of the bone.

But if you want to delete the bone influence for good you can select the group with the same name in the *Vertex Groups* list, click on the down arrow, on the right, and choose *Remove From All Groups*.

Now the group still exists but no more vertices are assigned to it.

As suggested by L0Lock, you can also delete the group ("-" button), it will avoid any problem if the *Normalize* function is used.

[image]

Comment: I recommend deleting the group instead. Otherwise, this group will still be taken into account in some weight painting operations, including normalizing which is the thing everyone uses all the time.

Comment: ok, edited, I didn't think about that because I never use Normalize   ;)

Comment: You should, especially via the auto-normalize brush option, as soon as you weight paint a rig more complex than a boxman. It saves you from a lot of troubles and headaches. ;)